# 2 very similar SQL queries have totally different performance

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing, query-performance

I have the following 2 SQL queries, which are 95% the same, but the performance is significantly different.

SQL query 1 (<0,1s):

```
SELECT CONCAT(a.`report_year`, '-', a. `report_month`) as `yearmonth`,
 AVG(a.cost_leasing/b.rate*IF(`report_year`=2016,0.73235,
       IF(`report_year`=2017,0.83430,1))) as average,
 'current' as `type`
FROM `vehicles` as a, `exchange_rates` as b
WHERE cid='3' AND
 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`, '-01'),
         '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-01-01' AND
 LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`,
        '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) <= '2017-06-30' AND
 `country` IN ('XX','UK') AND
 a.currency = b.currency AND
 b.`year` = `report_year` AND
 fxid=2
GROUP BY `yearmonth`
ORDER BY `yearmonth`;
```

Explain query 1:

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ref new_selectors,...   new_cost_leasing    4   const   10812   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...   
1   SIMPLE  b   ref PRIMARY,date,fxid   fxid    19  const,c1682fleet.a.report_year,c1682fleet.a.curren...   196 Using where; Using index
```

SQL query 2 (>3s):

```
SELECT CONCAT(c.`report_year`, '-', c.`report_month`) as `yearmonth`,
 AVG(c.cost_leasing/d.rate*IF(`report_year`=2016,0.73235,
        IF(`report_year`=2017,0.83430,1))),
 'baseline'
FROM `kpis` as c, `exchange_rates` as d
WHERE cid='3' AND
 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`, '-01'),
      '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-01-01' AND
 LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`,
            '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) <= '2017-06-30' AND
 `country` IN ('XX','UK') AND
 c.kid=1 AND
 c.currency = d.currency AND
 d.`year` = `report_year` AND
 fxid=2
GROUP BY `yearmonth`
ORDER BY `yearmonth`;
```

Explain query 2:

```
1   SIMPLE  c   ref oem_group,...   cost_leasing    8   const,const 30038   Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...   
1   SIMPLE  d   ref PRIMARY,date,fxid   fxid    19  const,c1682fleet.c.report_year,c1682fleet.c.curren...   196 Using where; Using index
```

SHOW INDEX FROM vehicles:

```
vehicles    0   PRIMARY 1   vid A   146068              BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    1   cid A   12              BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    2   cost_leasing    A   4564                BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    3   currency    A   5216                BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    4   report_month    A   24344               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    5   report_year A   29213               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    6   country A   36517               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    7   supplier    A   29213               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    8   jato_segment    A   24344               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    9   business_unit   A   36517               BTREE           
vehicles    1   new_cost_leasing    10  entity  A   73034               BTREE
```

SHOW INDEX FROM exchange_rates:

```
exchange_rates  0   PRIMARY 1   fxid    A   2               BTREE           
exchange_rates  0   PRIMARY 2   currency    A   160             BTREE           
exchange_rates  0   PRIMARY 3   date    A   569250              BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   date    1   fxid    A   2               BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   date    2   date    A   28462               BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   date    3   currency    A   569250              BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   date    4   rate    A   569250              BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   fxid    1   fxid    A   2               BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   fxid    2   year    A   114             BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   fxid    3   currency    A   2904                BTREE           
exchange_rates  1   fxid    4   rate    A   569250              BTREE
```

SHOW INDEX FROM kpis:

```
kpis    0   PRIMARY 1   vid A   60308               BTREE                   
kpis    1   cost_leasing    1   cid A   2               BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    2   kid A   2               BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    3   cost_leasing    A   78              BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    4   currency    A   78              BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    5   report_month    A   1096                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    6   report_year A   3350                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    7   country A   1884                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    8   supplier    A   4020                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    9   jato_segment    A   3015                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    10  business_unit   A   4307                BTREE           
kpis    1   cost_leasing    11  entity  A   6030                BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    1   cid A   2               BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    2   kid A   2               BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    3   country A   48              BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    4   report_year A   96              BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    5   currency    A   96              BTREE           
kpis    1   avg_cost    6   cost_leasing    A   172             BTREE
```

**Question:**
My question is, why there is such a significant performance difference (factor 30) even though there is just one additional criteria in query 2 (kid), which is even part of the index.

Anyone an idea how I can optimize query 2?

Comment: I wouldn't say they are 95% the same if they are using completely different tables. With potentially different structures, indexes, number of records... need more info.

Comment: tabels are the same beside the fact that kpis contains additionally the field `kid`. Indexes the same, they are equal beside the fact that the kpi indexes additionally contain `kid` as column.
The affected lines you can see in the explain answers.

Comment: Could you post your indexes definitions?

Comment: Please read this, and pay special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/  Please [edit] your question to provide more information. One of your indexes is probably missing a column, but we can't tell which one.

Comment: I added the relevant KPI index.

Comment: Note that an index for several fields is *not* the same that several individual indexes for each of those fields, have you tried creating an index just for the `kid` field?

Comment: What do you mean? I though only one index can be used per query and it has to contain all fields used in the where clause.

Comment: Please post individually,  1.  SHOW INDEX FROM vehicles;  2. SHOW INDEX FROM exchange_rates; 3. SHOW INDEX FROM kpis;  so we have some sense of rows/cardinality in each table.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I added them, didn't know this function, but it's indeed very helpful to understand the situation. I left out the irrelevant indexes to shorten the output, because with all indexes it would be a way too long output.

Comment: After testing a little bit, it looks like the problem is the average of `c.cost_leasing/d.rate`, the if condition doesn't seem to be problem. Without the `/d.rate`the query runs with nearly the same speed (obviously because of the missing join operation), but I don't understand why it's so slow and the same operation on the vehicle table is so fast, especially the cardinality is actually higher and not lower.

Comment: You might consider using sargable predicates for the date ranges. (As a general rule avoid functions on the data.)

Comment: @Used_By_Already please use the first query and show us your preparation and alternative of a query with 'sargabel predicates'.  You will be appreciated for your sharing.

Comment: These are problems, here you manipulate data to suit the the date parameters: 
 `STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(report_year, '-', report_month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-01-01' AND
 LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(report_year, '-', report_month, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) <= '2017-06-30'`
**do it the other way around** change the parameters to suit the data

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: the `exchange_rates` column `year` was not unique and the select of `vehicles` had just half size of the select of `kpis`, but because of the big cardinality of the not unique column `year` the join of `exchange_rates` and `kpis` created a temporary set of more than 2 million entries, which is very big for an average operation.

Solution: Instead of using `year` I used the unique column `date` and changed the condition to

```
`date` = MAKEDATE(`report_year`, 1)
```

Comment: If you KNOW globally more than ONE MILLION rows used within ONE SELECT does NOT make sense, this line in your my.cnf/ini   ---- sql_select_limit = 1M  # to STOP errant volume of data ---   will work for you during your tenure - or until someone removes it for your my.cfg.

Answer (score 0):

These are not sargable:

```
 STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-01-01' 

 LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(`report_year`, '-', `report_month`, '-01'), '%Y-%m-%d')) <= '2017-06-30'
```

For every row you are using 5 functions to concatenate and convert to dates, yet there are just 2 date constants being compared to. It would save a great deal of effort if you could reverse that and convert the 2 date constants into somethng that suits the unaltered data. Not only would you save on the computation effort of the functions, but you open up the possibility that indexes on `report_year` and `report_month` can be used.

I have not had time to test this much, and I'm guessing the columns invloved are integers, but I think a more sargable set of predicates for the date range handling would assist both queries. e.g.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa3c9/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`Report_Year` int, `Report_Month` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`Report_Year`, `Report_Month`)
VALUES
    (2015, 1), (2015, 2), (2015, 3),
    (2015, 4), (2015, 5), (2015, 6),
    (2015, 7), (2015, 8), (2015, 9),
    (2015, 10), (2015, 11), (2015, 12),
    (2016, 1), (2016, 2), (2016, 3),
    (2016, 4), (2016, 5), (2016, 6),
    (2016, 7), (2016, 8), (2016, 9),
    (2016, 10), (2016, 11), (2016, 12),
    (2017, 1), (2017, 2), (2017, 3),
    (2017, 4), (2017, 5), (2017, 6),
    (2017, 7), (2017, 8), (2017, 9),
    (2017, 10), (2017, 11), (2017, 12)
;
```

**Query **:

```
set @start := '2016-04-04';
set @end := '2017-01-30';

select *, @start, @end
from table1
where (
       ((year(@start) < year(@end)) AND report_year = year(@start) and report_month >= month(@start)) 
      OR
       ((year(@start) < year(@end)) AND report_year > year(@start) and report_year < year(@end)) 
      OR
       ((year(@start) <= year(@end)) AND report_year = year(@end) and report_month <= month(@end)) 
      )
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Report_Year | Report_Month |     @start |       @end |
|-------------|--------------|------------|------------|
|        2016 |            4 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |            5 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |            6 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |            7 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |            8 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |            9 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |           10 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |           11 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2016 |           12 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
|        2017 |            1 | 2016-04-04 | 2017-01-30 |
```

**[Results]**:

```
set @start := '2016-01-01';
set @end := '2016-06-30';

| Report_Year | Report_Month |     @start |       @end |
|-------------|--------------|------------|------------|
|        2016 |            1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |
|        2016 |            2 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |
|        2016 |            3 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |
|        2016 |            4 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |
|        2016 |            5 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |
|        2016 |            6 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-06-30 |

set @start := '2016-01-01';
set @end := '2017-06-30';
```

**[Results]**:

```
| Report_Year | Report_Month |     @start |       @end |
|-------------|--------------|------------|------------|
|        2016 |            1 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            2 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            3 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            4 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            5 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            6 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            7 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            8 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |            9 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |           10 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |           11 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2016 |           12 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            1 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            2 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            3 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            4 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            5 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
|        2017 |            6 | 2016-01-01 | 2017-06-30 |
```

Comment: Thank you for the examples to work toward 'sargable predicates'.

Comment: Semicolons are missing, in the query for sqlfiddle.com   Again, Thanks.

Comment: Semi colons exited at sqlfiddle, but were dropped  when choosing the markup layout... possible sqlfiddle bug in that layout.

Comment: By the way, if altering the data model is an option i would suggest use of a date field instead of year and month columns.

Answer (score 0):

Sargable is a strong point.  Dealing better with `dates` is a point.  Here are some more points.

An 11-column index is almost guaranteed to be a waste.  Even a 6-column index is unlikely to be fully used.  Only the leftmost columns of an index will be used.  Usually it gets to a point where the next column is not useful, so it stops.

Generally it is not a good idea to split dates into year, month, and day.  Since you seem to need only year and month, a suggestion would be `CHAR(7) CHARSET ascii` with values like '2017-06'.  Or do you actually have reports that stop in the middle of a month?

Please qualify each column name with the table involved.  It is very important that we know which table, for example, `fxid` is in.

Please use the `JOIN .. ON` syntax:

```
FROM vehicles AS a
JOIN exchange_rates AS b  ON a.currency = b.currency
```

(I would prefer `AS v` and `AS er` as a mnemonic.)

Desired indexes (with current year/mo columns):

```
b,d: INDEX(fxid, currency, year)
a: INDEX(cid, currency, report_year)
c: INDEX(kid, cid, currency, report_year)
```

More on creating indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql